# python FPDF not sizing correctly

Tags: python, fpdf

I am getting a list of images from a directory and I am trying to convert a list of images to PDF. I am getting their width and height and using Image module. When the program runs and I open the PDF file, the picture look very big and only a corner of the pic.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

image_directory = '/Users/myuser/pics/'
extensions = ('*.jpg','*.png','*.gif')
pdf = FPDF()
imagelist=[]
for ext in extensions:
    imagelist.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(image_directory,ext)))

for imageFile in imagelist:
    cover = Image.open(imageFile)
    width, height = cover.size
    pdf.add_page()
    # 1 px = 0.264583 mm (FPDF default is mm)
    pdf.image(imageFile, 0, 0, float(width * 0.264583), float(height * 0.264583))
pdf.output(image_directory + "file.pdf", "F")
```

The image is the left one and the right is the PDF
[image]

Comment: I think `cover.size` will return size in pixels and FPDF defaults size to `mm`. The acceptable units for FPDF are `pt`, `cm`, `in`. You can convert the `cover.size` to `pt` or `cm` or `in` for your pdf.

Comment: After I converted to mm, now the picture is missing the quarter of the picture.

Comment: Think it depends on the monitor size too. Try to correct that.

Comment: I updated the problem. The pictures now come out the right size, but the box container is in like a printer page size. Do you know how to change every container to be in the same size than the picture?

Comment: You can set it by passing arugments to FPDF like `FPDF('P', 'mm', (100, 150))` which set it to _100X150 mm_ in Portrait mode

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue is with **the image size exceeding the pdf size** ( A4 by default) which is 210mm x 297 mm in portrait and inverse in landscape. You should check and resize according. You could also set page orientation according to the height and width of the page.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

image_directory = '/Users/myuser/pics/'
extensions = ('*.jpg','*.png','*.gif')
pdf = FPDF()
imagelist=[]
for ext in extensions:
imagelist.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(image_directory,ext)))

for imageFile in imagelist:
    cover = Image.open(imageFile)
    width, height = cover.size

    # convert pixel in mm with 1px=0.264583 mm
    width, height = float(width * 0.264583), float(height * 0.264583)

    # given we are working with A4 format size 
    pdf_size = {'P': {'w': 210, 'h': 297}, 'L': {'w': 297, 'h': 210}}

    # get page orientation from image size 
    orientation = 'P' if width < height else 'L'

    #  make sure image size is not greater than the pdf format size
    width = width if width < pdf_size[orientation]['w'] else pdf_size[orientation]['w']
    height = height if height < pdf_size[orientation]['h'] else pdf_size[orientation]['h']

    pdf.add_page(orientation=orientation)

    pdf.image(imageFile, 0, 0, width, height)
pdf.output(image_directory + "file.pdf", "F")
```

Comment: Instead of all of this, you can easily solve the problem by just setting a width or height in mm for the image. FPDF will automatically resize it for you, maintaining aspect ratio. This way, you can just set it to be the width of the page with pdf.w if you want it to fill the whole page

Comment: @TaehanStott But what if I have a mix of very tall and very wide images? How will I know if which is better to set (width or height)?

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf = FPDF(unit='mm')
for imageFile in selected_list:
    cover = Image.open(imageFile)
    width, height = cover.size
    width, height = float(width * 0.264583), float(height * 0.264583)
    pdf.add_page(format=(width, height))
    pdf.image(imageFile, 0, 0, width, height)
    name = "output.pdf"
    pdf.output(name)
```